# ¿Cómo enviar un array de objetos por postman?

Tags: post, postman

¿Cómo puedo enviar este dato por postman?

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Comment: Por favor, pulsa en [edit] para mostrar además el código _como texto, con formato_. No todos pueden ver las imágenes.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Al añadir un corchete '[' esto indica que vas a pasar un Array, pero en tu código estás pasando un objeto, por lo que tienes que indicar los parámetros entre llaves '{'.

```
{
    "commerce_id": 1,
    "interests": {
         "question": 1,
         "answer": 1
    }
}
```

EDITADO:

Como bien dice @L.Ronquillo en los comentarios, si lo que necesitas que interests sea un Array debería ser de la siguiente manera para poder añadir mas elementos 'interests':

```
{
    "commerce_id": 1,
    "interests": [{
         "question": 1,
         "answer": 1
    }]
}
```

Comment: depende de su petición. Si explícitamente necesita enviar un array ahí, sería poner el array e inicial su objeto.

Comment: @L.Ronquillo y seguramente tienes toda la razón del mundo viendo su [siguiente pregunta](https://es.stackoverflow.com/questions/543803/error-php-laravel-7-0)