# Error php laravel 7.0

Tags: php, laravel

tengo este dato que envio por postman

```
{
    "commerce_id": 1,
    "interests": {
         "question": 1,
         "answer": 1
    }
}
```

y este es mi codigo en php;

```
  function storeInterst($interestsData, $commerce_id)
    {
        try {
            $interests = [];
            foreach ($interestsData as $interest) {
                echo $commerce_id;
                echo $interest['question'] . "\n";
                echo $interest['answer'] . "\n";
                $interests[] = $this->commerceInterest->setDataRegister($interest['answer'], $commerce_id, $interest['question']);
            }
            echo "hola";
            die;
            $this->commerceInterest->insert($interests);
        } catch (\Exception $exception) {
            throw new \Exception($exception->getMessage());
        }
    }
}
```

el caso es que la funcion no me imprime nada de del foreach y se que los datos estan entrando por que la variable cuando la imprimio como $interestsData me vota los datos si especifico $interestsData["answer"]

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Viendo tu [pregunta anterior](https://es.stackoverflow.com/questions/543794/como-puedo-enviar-este-array-por-postman) me pregunto si la respuesta era acertada, pues en esta intentas recorrer un objeto como un array cuando no lo es.

Prueba cambiando esto:

```
{
    "commerce_id": 1,
    "interests": {
         "question": 1,
         "answer": 1
    }
}
```

por esto:

```
{
    "commerce_id": 1,
    "interests": [{
         "question": 1,
         "answer": 1
    }]
}
```

para que, si hay más datos, algun dia pueda ser así:

```
{
    "commerce_id": 1,
    "interests": [{
         "question": 1,
         "answer": 1
    },{
         "question": 2,
         "answer": 3
    },{
         "question": 3,
         "answer": 1
    }]
}
```

y de ese modo tener un array real que puedas recorrer en ese **foreach** que haces después.

Por cierto, no se ve como recoges el json en tu pregunta, pero para que te funcione con tu código actual, donde representa que los objetos han sido convertidos a array, deberás usar el parámetro `true` durante el uso de [json_decode()](https://www.php.net/manual/es/function.json-decode.php) para que lo convierta **todo** a arrays asociativos, más o menos de este modo:

```php
$datos_recibidos = json_decode($loqueseaquerecibes, true);
$commerce_id = $datos_recibidos['commerce_id'];
$interestsData = $datos_recibidos['interests'];
storeInterst($interestsData, $commerce_id);
```

Comment: con lo primero lo arregle como estaba enviado el json estaba mal, el otro que me mandas no lo probe por que ya con lo primero me funciono muchas gracias.